# Required columns missing in SSAS Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, business-intelligence, tabular

I have SSAS 2017 model where I have renamed few columns in design mode.

So in the table and partition definition I have a column named PowerQueryColumn, whereas in design the same column is renamed to BusinessName.

The code of the model for table definition looks like this:

```
"columns": [
      {
        "name": "BusinessName",
        "dataType": "string",
        "sourceColumn": "PowerQueryColumn"
      },
```

And this works perfectly fine on the server after deployment, but when I try to validate this partition in VS I get this error:

> Cannot import the partition query because the set of columns in the partition definition does not match those in the table definition. The following required columns are missing: BusinessName

I have already made this change multiple times, but in this case I get an error message for the first time, although it works on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to manually change source columns to match name column in .bim file. And after this I renamed them in the Power Query instead of the Design mode in the Tabular. From user perspective nothing was changed, but now the Validation of partition works.

I don't know what have caused this problem to appear in the first place as column renaming is one of the basic possibilities for AS :/